# How to commit a regex-variable to the action-script in fail2ban?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'd like to use a `regex-variable` to commit a *CIDR* subnet mask from the filter.conf to the action.conf. The idea is to to block/ban an ip-range with [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org). Since **iptables** works with *CIDR* I would like to use it via fail2ban. Is this possible?

---

So I would like to commit the *failregex variable* `mask` to the action-script. Here is my failregex creating the `mask`variable:

**filter.d/test-filter.conf**

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>\/(?P<mask>(8|16|24|32))
```

---

My test-string looks like this: `10.10.10.10/16    [2015-02-11 12:00:00]`.

---

This is my *action-script* which works fine if I set the `mask` variable directly or via the *jail.local* (like: `action = test-action[mask=16]`).

**action.d/test-action.conf**

```
[Definition]
...
actionban = iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip>/<mask> -j DROP
actionunban = iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip>/<mask> -j DROP
...

[Init]
# Option:  mask
# Notes.:  used to ban an address-range by netmask(s) in CIDR notation.
# Values:  [ 32 | 24 | 16 | 8 ] Default: 32
#
mask = 32
```

Here is my jail.local (without any variable set).

**jail.local**

```
[test]
enabled   = true
action    = test-action
filter    = test-filter
logpath   = /etc/fail2ban/test.log
maxretry  = 5
findtime  = 1000
bantime   = -1
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `mask` group you set and what is the result?

Comment: Yes, i did. But i got no idea how the groups/variables get from the filter-script to the action-script. Like `<ip>`, ´ <failures>`, `<time>` etc.
I tried something like this: `echo (?P=mask) $+{mask} ${mask} \g<mask>  {mask} (mask) <mask> [mask] \{mask\} mask (?P<mask>)` ...

Comment: Did you not solve this here? http://sven.rojek.de/posts/fail2ban-iprange-mit-blackliste-blocken

Comment: Nope, that's actually only a workaround. I created several *filter* (for different masks) and each tiggers another action via the *jail.local* These could be avoided if I were able to pass that parameter directly to the *action-script*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question was asked, there is a little-documented way to use such variables to pass data from the filter to the action:
You simply have to precede your variable name with 'F-' and the whole thing must be uppercase..
So, in your case, in your filter, you would use:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>\/(?P<F-MASK>(8|16|24|32)</F-MASK>)
```

and your action would look like this:

```
[Definition]
...
actionban = iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s <ip>/<F-MASK> -j DROP
actionunban = iptables -D fail2ban-<name> -s <ip>/<F-MASK> -j DROP
...
```

Sorry for reviving an old question..

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **NO**. The tags `<ip> <matches> <failures> etc.` are all special tags provided by fail2ban, and you can't access any data from captured groups of the filter regex within ACTIONS.

I've opened a issue in the fail2ban project for such functionality.
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1110